# store the country ID from country drop down box in mysql but it is storing as 0 in db

Tags: php, mysql

```
//This is my php to view dropdown box  <?php
include('connect.php');
//for retriving data from DB and show it in drop down box
    $query="SELECT cname FROM country";
    $result = mysqli_query ($con, "$query");
    echo "<select name=country value=''>";
      while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
        echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
?>
```

But when i am storing in DB my country_id is always 0.

Comment: `//This is to store ID of the selected value from Drop down box
$country_name=$_POST['country']; //Storing selected country name in variable
$country_id=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT countryid FROM country WHERE ('cname'='$country_name')"); //Storing Country ID for the stored country name
$country_id_array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_id);
$country_id=$country_id_array['countryid'];`

Comment: Put this in Question not in comment

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching country id from SQL Query

Change

```
$query="SELECT cname FROM country";
```

To

```
$query="SELECT cid, cname FROM country"; // Update cid with your country id field
```

Therefore `$r[0]` is getting blank value.

Comment: Thks a lot. But in here i need to display only country name in my html drop down box. But i need to store the country id of that country name.

Comment: If i do like the above code means, it display only country id in my drop down box and stores only 0 in my database.

Answer (score 0):

I am going with Pupil's answer to change the query to

```
$query="SELECT cid, cname FROM country"; // Update cid with your country id field
```

and then change this

```
  echo "<select name=country value=''>";
```

to

```
 echo "<select name=country>"; //remove value=''
```

EDIT:

Please check your column type may be it is "INT" when you try to store text it stores 0.

Comment: `<select>` element does not have `value` attribute. Its `<option>`s have it.

Comment: Ya i had removed value=' ' . But the problem is i need to store countryid from my country table to another table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your reference

```
//This is my php to view dropdown box 
 <?php
    include('connect.php');
    //for retriving data from DB and show it in drop down box
    $query="SELECT countryid,cname FROM country";
    $result = mysqli_query ($con, "$query");
    echo "<select name='country'>";
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='$r[countryid]'> $r[cname] </option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
 ?>
```

Comment: if i do $query="SELECT countryid,cname FROM country"; it displays only the countryid in my drop down box.

Comment: And if i do this line echo "<option value='$r[countryid]'> $r[cname] </option>"; it displays nothing in my dropdown box.

Comment: But if i edit it as $query="SELECT cname FROM country"; and echo "<option value='$r[countryid]'> $r[0] </option>"; then it works well but it storing the value as 0 in my database. Please help.

Comment: u should enter the correct database table field name

Comment: $country_name=$_POST['country']; //Storing selected country name in variable
$country_id=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT countryid FROM country WHERE ('cname'='$country_name')"); //Storing Country ID for the stored country name
$country_id_array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_id);
$country_id=$country_id_array['countryid'];

 $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sample (user_id, username, email, password, address, country_id,gender)VALUES ('$user_id', '$username', '$email', '$password', '$address', '$country_id' , '$gender')");

Comment: Use   **echo $country_name=$_POST['country']; **  to find the error

Comment: that $country_name has the value of selected country's country_id

Comment: $country_name=$_POST['country'];
// It has the value of countryid
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sample (user_id, username, email, password, address, country_id,gender)VALUES ('$user_id', '$username', '$email', '$password', '$address', '$country_name' , '$gender')");

Comment: u use this query to insert the values